# How to load another PHP's phpmyadmin to current PHP

Tags: php, database

In my application there are two PHP are available.

1) PHP 5.1.6

2) PHP 5.2.6

Currently I am using PHP 5.2.6 version in my application.
Also I'm using PHP 5.2.6 database ( phpmyadmin ).

Here my question is I want to use another PHP's database ( phpmyadmin ) i.e. PHP 5.1.6 's phpmyadmin.

I dont know how to do this, Please give me ur suggestions, in which file should i make change for accessing correct database in my application.

Thanks

-Pravin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin runs with PHP 5.1.6 as well as with PHP 5.2.6 and several other versions of PHP.

Comment: ohhhhh....is it so...you are saying that no need of doing this dababase redirection....only one phpMyAdmin available for all php version? Thanks

Comment: phpMyAdmin is no database. It's merely a web-based frontend for MySQL written in PHP. So yes, you'll only need one installation of phpMyAdmin on your server even if you run more than one PHP version in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're asking if the version of phpadmin you use to manage the database affects the version you use to run your application.  It does not.  The version of PHP you use for your application and phpmyadmin *do not* have to match.